# Buscar valores de un array en otro y devolver una posicion especifica

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo estos dos array, el primero esta conformado por claves foraneas que vienen de la BD y el segundo por el detalle de una de esas claves foraneas.
Como puedo hacer para recorrer la posicion 0 de mi primer array y buscar en el segundo el valor de esa posicion y devolver el detDeterminante:

```
(6) ["1", "1", "si", "1", "37", "238,835,836"]
    0:"1"
    1:"1"
    2:"si"
    3:"1"
    4:"37"
    5:"238,835,836"
    length:6

(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0:{0: "1", 1: "DATO 1", idDeterminante: "1", detDeterminante: "DATO 1"}
    1:{0: "2", 1: "DATO 2", idDeterminante: "2", detDeterminante: "DATO 2"}
    2:{0: "3", 1: "DATO 3", idDeterminante: "3", detDeterminante: "DATO 3"}
    3:{0: "4", 1: "DATO 4", idDeterminante: "4", detDeterminante: "DATO 4"}
    length:4
```

Ej:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi primer array tengo el valor 1 en la posicion 0.
Quiero buscar ese valor en las distintas posiciones del array dos y al encontrarlo devolver el detDeterminante que le corresponda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes buscar comparando el indice 0 del primer array con la propiedad idDeterminante del segundo.  Algo asi:

```js
var lista1= ["1", "1", "si", "1", "37", "238,835,836"];
var lista2= [
    {0: "1", 1: "DATO 1", idDeterminante: "1", detDeterminante: "DATO 1"},
    {0: "2", 1: "DATO 2", idDeterminante: "2", detDeterminante: "DATO 2"},
    {0: "3", 1: "DATO 3", idDeterminante: "3", detDeterminante: "DATO 3"},
    {0: "4", 1: "DATO 4", idDeterminante: "4", detDeterminante: "DATO 4"}
];

function buscar_en(posicion){
    var obtenido= lista2.filter( function( item){  
        return item.idDeterminante == posicion;
    })[0];
    console.log(  obtenido.detDeterminante);
}

buscar_en(lista1[0]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

```
var lista1= ["1", "1", "si", "1", "37", "238,835,836"];
var lista2= [
    {0: "1", 1: "DATO 1", idDeterminante: "1", detDeterminante: "DATO 1"},
    {0: "2", 1: "DATO 2", idDeterminante: "2", detDeterminante: "DATO 2"},
    {0: "3", 1: "DATO 3", idDeterminante: "3", detDeterminante: "DATO 3"},
    {0: "4", 1: "DATO 4", idDeterminante: "4", detDeterminante: "DATO 4"}
];

function buscar_en(posicion){
    var obtenido= lista2.filter( function( item){  
        return item.idDeterminante == lista1[ posicion]; //  posicion 0
    })[0];
    console.log(  obtenido.detDeterminante);
}

buscar_en(0);
```